# Add Locale/Resources at runtime

Tags: android, android-resources

I want to add languages for my app from server , so I can manage them dynamically at runtime. 
I mean if my app support `en` and `de` languages , if I wanted to support new languages, I want just to download the new resources (`string.xml`) and make new directory for this new values (`values-fr` say) from server
is that possible ?

Comment: You can use a database with the localized strings, instead. You can dowload the strings (query from the server and store into the local table). Then implement a system to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android does not support this through the resource system. Resources must be compiled into the app. You are welcome to come up with your own system for downloading strings, determining which ones to use based on locale, and so forth, but you will be doing so without using resources.

Comment: Thanks @CommosWare
if it is possible , it will save me alot of time , but I have as you said to manage it myself :(